# TIdMessage mandatory subject field

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy

I am using `TIdMessage` and when I assign empty subject e.g. `IdMsg->Subject = "";` outgoing message does not have `"Subject:"` header.

If I add subject by having a space e.g. `IdMsg->Subject = " ";` then the message has Subject: header even though it trims the space - the output is not: `"Subject:[sp][sp][cr][lf]"` but it is `"Subject:[cr][lf]"`. This is clearly not consistent with the rest of headers which all have a space after the colon and before actual data so the empty subject should be `"Subject:[sp][sp][cr][lf]"`.

I understand that the `TIdMessage` tries to optimize message by removing headers or trimming them but it is just being too smart here.

Is there a way to force having a `Subject` header with 2 spaces behind it (without editing the TIdMessage source code)?

For those wondering about the reason - I want to make sure that dumb email reading programs/scripts correctly interpret as "empty subject" which is the reason for all of this and not as something else and removing Subject: header is not much of an optimization anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your space character actually survives the encoding process when `TIdMessageClient` is generating the header data being sent, but then the space is getting trimmed by `TIdHeaderList` when it is parsing the final header data and folding long headers to fit within email line length restrictions.  Each line generated for a given header by the folding process gets right-trimmed, and since your header data only consists of whitespace, it gets discarded.

The only way to disable that folding is to set the `TIdMessage.LastGeneratedHeaders.FoldLines` property to False, which is not advisable unless you know your headers will always be short enough to never need folding.

Another option is to set the `TIdMessage.Subject` to a blank string, and then use the `TIdMessage.ExtraHeaders` property instead.  You will have to use `ExtraHeaders.Add()` instead of `ExtraHeaders.Values` so that the string is added as-is and avoids folding:

```
Msg.ExtraHeaders.Add('Subject:  ');
```

Comment: Is there then an advisable way? Adding custom headers? I hope you won't fix this as a bug now because I do require to have Subject included as empty...